# Google Maps API or Google Maps SDK

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps

For a current project for both IOS and Android I am required to use the night theme which already exists in android after a certain time and in ios if you double click the home button.

I know the Mobile SDKs do not support this; however, the Javascript API does. I require a map with custom markers and the ability to query information about businesses to be used for custom pop ups.

Would it be wise to use the Javascript version with webkit or find a completely different solution?

Comment: I would use JavaScript API because it has more features than SDK. The Places API for iOS is limited compared to JavaScript version

Comment: I have heard from Somewhere that the previous update to v3 broke alot of existing maps was this true?